# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol nuget Casablanca

Tags: c++

So im trying to use the nuget package casablanca in my project. 
When im building my projects hes creating the project.lib and also a casablanca.dll.
But when i try to build my main project with the exe there are Linker erorrs.
So im wondering now why are there LNK errors when using a nuget package?

I tried to add the casablanca.lib from the microsoft sdk folder but that doesnt help.
Did anyone have similar problems??

im getting errors like :

```
18 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall web::json::value::value(void)" (_imp??0value@json@web@@QAE@XZ)"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Have u added the lib file using #pragma in your main file? If not, please add it in your code

Comment: yes i added #pragma comment(lib, "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Cpp REST SDK for Visual Studio 2013/SDK/lib/x86/Release/casablanca120.lib") to my main.cpp and my cpp file where i use the lib...

Comment: Please add the library path to visual studio settings and just write .lib file name in #pragma. It is having lots of spaces and \ symbol. Sometimes it may lead to this problem.

Comment: ok i did it that way but im still getting the exact same errors, i think its maybe an outdated lib because its 120 and the actual nuget package is 2.0. But i cant find any other lib file...

Comment: ok found the 2.0.lib file but im still getting link errors.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: class pplx::task<class web::http::http_response> __thiscall web::http::client::http_client::request(class web::http::http_request,class pplx::cancellation_token)" (_imp(__imp_?request@http_client@client@http@web@@QAE?AV?$task@Vhttp_response@http@web@@@pplx@@Vhttp_request@34@Vcancellation_token@6@@Z)".